# How to get unobtrusive validation markup in my custom tag helper

Tags: validation, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Is there an easy way, in an ASP.Net Core custom tag helper, to get the HTML markup that would have been emitted by the `<span asp-validation-for="xxx">` tag helper?

In other words, can I get something equivalent to `HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor()` in my tag helper? Or do I need to recreate this myself by digging through the `ModelExpression.ModelMetadata` properties?

Background:

I have authored tag helpers that add Bootstrap markup around common HTML elements such as `<input>`, `<button>`, etc. In addition to adding Bootstrap markup, these tag helpers also add unobtrusive validation markup after "input" elements:

```
<span class='field-validation-valid' data-valmsg-for='{name}' data-valmsg-replace='true'></span>
```

This works great for client-side validation because the JavaScript sees the data-* attributes and does its thing. **But this doesn't work for server-side validation.** If a server-side validator returns an error message, the message doesn't show up on the form.

A little experimentation shows that the `<span asp-validation-for="xxx">` tag helper (which I am NOT using) works with server-side validators to modify the HTML sent to the client if the associated model variable has a validation error. The modified HTML contains the error message provided by the validator:

```
<span class='field-validation-error' data-valmsg-for='{name}' data-valmsg-replace='true'>Some error message.</span>
```

So, my tag helpers need to do the same thing and emit either normal or error validation message markup.

It would be really simple if my tag helper could emit a `<span asp-validation-for="xxx">` element, but, as far as I can tell, there is no way to cause HTML created by my tag helper to be interpreted as tag helpers.

I can dig through the model metadata and discover the error message and format the validation message `<span>` tag appropriately, but all of that work is already done for me (and probably more correctly than I could do it) by `HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor()` and by the `validation-for` span tag helper.

FWIW, [this article](http://blog.techdominator.com/article/using-html-helper-inside-tag-helpers.html) shows some magic that allows a tag helper to access the `HtmlHelper`. I'd rather avoid that path and use something that smells more like native "tag helper" code if I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having this issue I was able to achieve the desired functionality by repurposing the existing ValidationMessageTagHelper in a TagHelper of my own. If you make sure to call the ProcessAsync method on the ValidationMessageTagHelper like in this line:

```
await validation.ProcessAsync(validationContext, validationOutput);
```

It will make create the validation you were expecting using the server-side validation from ViewData.
My custom validation tag helper that worked with server-side validation looked like:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("validation")]
public class CustomValidationTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private IHtmlGenerator _htmlGenerator;

    public CustomValidationTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator)
    {
        _htmlGenerator = htmlGenerator;
    }

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {

        var validationContext = CreateTagHelperContext();
        var validationOutput = CreateTagHelperOutput("span");

        var validation = new ValidationMessageTagHelper(_htmlGenerator)
        {
            For = For,
            ViewContext = ViewContext,

        };

        await validation.ProcessAsync(validationContext, validationOutput);
        validationOutput.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "field-validation-error text-danger");

        output.TagName = "";


        output.Content.AppendHtml(validationOutput);
    }

    private static TagHelperContext CreateTagHelperContext()
    {
        return new TagHelperContext(
            new TagHelperAttributeList(),
            new Dictionary<object, object>(),
            Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
    }

    private static TagHelperOutput CreateTagHelperOutput(string tagName)
    {
        return new TagHelperOutput(
            tagName,
            new TagHelperAttributeList(),
            (a, b) =>
            {
                var tagHelperContent = new DefaultTagHelperContent();
                tagHelperContent.SetContent(string.Empty);
                return Task.FromResult<TagHelperContent>(tagHelperContent);
            });
    }
}
```

and is used like so on a page:

```
<validation asp-for="Username" />
```